# Is it required to use AFCI/GFCI breaker when replacing subpanel?

Tags: gfci, subpanel, nec, afci

I'm replacing my subpanel at home. My jurisdiction adopts NEC 2017.

- When replacing a subpanel, is it required to have CAFCI on all circuit breakers for all 120V circuits?
- When replacing a subpanel, is it required to have GFCI on all kitchen, bath, garage, etc 120/240V circuits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what you're starting with, and what else is part of the scope of work.

If the scope of work is "replace subpanel" for a good reason, e.g. to get more spaces, dangerous (Zinsco), or obsolete (Pushmatic)... that does not trigger a requirement to upgrade breakers to AFCI or GFCI.  So you can simply stay with the same breaker types as you have now.

If it's part of something bigger, like a renovation, then you may be required to update to current-Code breakers for those circuits that are part of the renovation.